# How can I create columns in Html/MVC?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to create columns of links in an MVC2 view, like this:

```
a g m
b h n
c i o
d j
e k 
f l
```

I could build a table row by row, doing some math to determine which items should be in the row, or I could build a table per column, but I'm hoping there's a simpler way to do this.

Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS for this an not tables.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/